# How can find domain name in Grape::API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

I am not able to fetch request object in Grape::API, My method is

## module Artical

module Railsapp
  module V1
    class Articleapi < Grape::API
      include Railsapp::V1::Defaults

```
  resource :articleapi do
    desc "Return all article"

    get "", root: :articles do
        error!({:error_message => "Please provide a article id."}, 422)
    end

    desc "Return a acticle"

    params do
      requires :id, type: String, desc: "ID of the photo"
    end

    get ":id", root: "photo" do

      @Artical = Contents.where(id: params[:id],content_type: 'Article').first

      if @Artical.present?
        error!({:success_message => "Record found",:result => @Artical }, 300)
      else
        error!({:error_message => "Record Could not found"}, 422)
      end
      # Photos.where(:id =>  @id).update_all(publish_status: @status_value)
    end
  end
```

Comment: there seems to be some typo's. I'm not sure if it was intended or not.  I can see `Artical` and `article` used interchanged

Comment: I am not getting the request object in any method and above code is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

In any grape endpoint you can access the request object as "request".
The request object has many methods available to access its various parameters.

For example: If you want to access the path details of a request then :

```
request.path_info
```

will give the path details of the current request.If you want to know various methods available for request object, just print and check :

```
request.methods
```